# Communication from WCF Service to UWP Application

Tags: c#, wcf, win-universal-app, publish-subscribe, duplex

I am currently building a WCF Service to make use of some DLL's that are not UWP compatible at the moment. I've gotten my service running, included, and accessible from my UWP app but because I'm very new to WCF I'm not sure the best way to go about reporting the status of certain activities of the WCF Service. Specifically, I have a function that I call from my service that does some things, reaches a certain point, and then does some more things. I would like the notify the UWP app that this certain point has been reached. How would I go about doing this?

I've looked into callbacks but I haven't found a clear resource on them and am hoping there is a simpler way to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Edit: After doing some reading on the various forms of communication in WCF(mainly duplex and subpub) I think my solution will be more along the lines of subpub although it seems like overkill. From what I've seen I would be unable to make 2 callback calls from within one service function call and that would be ideal.

Edit: So apparently I am able to make 2 callback calls from a service function by modifying my ServiceContract to something like:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, 
    CallbackContract = typeof(IRecordServiceCallback_duplex),         
    CallbackContract = typeof(IRecordServiceCallback_duplex))]
```

So now I know that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

**Update:**
My problem now, I've looked through various examples and none of them seem to implement a duplex wcf service without some other complications which make understanding what's going on a bit difficult. Or they are missing the config file. Ideally I think I'd like to have a Duplex WCF Service hosted in IIS that communicates to a Windows Universal App, I'm currently hung up on how to call my duplex wcf service from within a UWP app. I've called a basic WCF Service before so I'm sure it can be done.